# ERROR Stopping due to error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/debezium/util/IoUtil

Tags: windows, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm trying to connect my SQL Server database to kafka on windows, i downloaded Debezium jar files, they are in a folder named debezium-connector-sqlserver, here's what it looks like : [Kafka folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cexS4.png), [Debezium folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nok06.png)

I also added this line`plugin.path=C:\\current_kafka_2.12-2.0.0\\debezium-connector-sqlserver` in connect-standalone.properties, it's where i put all the jar files i downloaded from Debezium.

i also created a file named connect-mssql.properties, and i put this in it.

```
name=inventory-connector
connector.class=io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector
tasks.max=2
database.hostname=DESKTOP-LMJGRO0
database.port=1433
database.user=sa
database.password=password
database.dbname=Source
database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
database.history.kafka.topic=test
table.whitelist=dbo.guinea_pig_source
```

Now when i try to run this .\bin\windows\connect-standalone .\config\connect-standalone.properties  .\config\connect-mssql.properties

I get the following error:

```
[2019-02-20 17:18:39,794] ERROR Stopping due to error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/debezium/util/IoUtil
        at io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.Module.<clinit>(Module.java:19)
        at io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector.version(SqlServerConnector.java:29)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.versionFor(DelegatingClassLoader.java:346)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.versionFor(DelegatingClassLoader.java:351)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.getPluginDesc(DelegatingClassLoader.java:328)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanPluginPath(DelegatingClassLoader.java:309)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanUrlsAndAddPlugins(DelegatingClassLoader.java:240)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.registerPlugin(DelegatingClassLoader.java:232)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initPluginLoader(DelegatingClassLoader.java:201)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initLoaders(DelegatingClassLoader.java:178)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.java:61)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.debezium.util.IoUtil
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:104)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 12 more
```

Comment: Hi, where have you unpacked the Debezium plugin?

Comment: it's in a folder named 'debezium-connector-sqlserver' i put the whole thing in the kafka folder.

Comment: try unpacking the debezium plugin to /plugins folder in the kafka-connect folder

Comment: Note: Kafka + Kafka Connect is not throughly tested in a Windows environment. The `plugin.path` might not work

Comment: Can you share the contents of the _debezium-connector-sqlserver_ folder? Specifically, it must contain the _debezium-connector-sqlserver-<version>.jar_ and the _debezium-core-<version>.jar_ and the SQL Server driver JAR. Also note that the archives for that connector for Debezium 0.9.0 and 0.9.1 actually contain *too many* dependencies by accident (also test dependencies etc.) This will be fixed in 0.9.2, due next week.

Comment: @Amine did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

All plugin files must be in subdirectroy of "plugin.path=". For example if plugin path is:

```
plugin.path=F:/connect-plugins/
```

Create directory F:/connect-plugins/mssql-debezium with folowing files:

- debezium-connector-sqlserver-0.9.2.Final.jar
- debezium-core-0.9.2.Final.jar
- mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar

Answer (score 1):

Add the connector jar files and kafka library files to the classpath :

In linux:
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/debezium-connector-sqlserver/*

export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH://kafka/libs/*

Answer (score 0):

Try nesting your **"debezium-connector-sqlserver"** inside another folder e.g: *"plugins"*
and update your **connect-standalone.properties** as
**plugin.path=C:\current_kafka_2.12-2.0.0\plugins**

Thus your directory structure will be like,
**C:\current_kafka_2.12-2.0.0\plugins\debezium-connector-sqlserver**
and your jars will be located inside **"debezium-connector-sqlserver"**

Answer (score 0):

Adding the trailing slash at the end of the plugin path variable solved the issue in my case.

```
plugin.path=**C:/Application/kafka/plugins/**
```