# ERROR Stopping due to error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/debezium/util/IoUtil

Tags: debezium

#### Objective

I am trying to connect to my Oracle Database(12c) from Kafka Connect(ideally in distributed mode) using the Debezium connector(1.2.4.Final). The Kafka version i am using is 2.13-2.6.0.

#### Command used

As per mentioned [here](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect_running), i am running this command:

```
C:\Users\username\Downloads\kafka>bin\windows\connect-distributed.bat config\connect-distributed.properties
```

#### Error

The error i am getting is:

> ERROR Stopping due to error
> (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed)
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/debezium/util/IoUtil
> at io.debezium.connector.oracle.Module.(Module.java:19)
> at io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnector.version(OracleConnector.java:23)
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.versionFor(DelegatingClassLoader.java:390)
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.versionFor(DelegatingClassLoader.java:395)
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.getPluginDesc(DelegatingClassLoader.java:365)
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanPluginPath(DelegatingClassLoader.java:337)
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanUrlsAndAddPlugins(DelegatingClassLoader.java:268)
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.registerPlugin(DelegatingClassLoader.java:260)
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initPluginLoader(DelegatingClassLoader.java:229)
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initLoaders(DelegatingClassLoader.java:206)
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.(Plugins.java:61)
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.startConnect(ConnectDistributed.java:91)
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.main(ConnectDistributed.java:78)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.debezium.util.IoUtil
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:104)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
> ... 13 more

#### Settings

In my connect-distributed.properties, i have this:

```
plugin.path=C:/Users/username/Downloads/kafka/libs/debezium
```

And inside the debezium folder(following Gunnar's recommendation from the comment in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54791140/error-stopping-due-to-error-org-apache-kafka-connect-cli-connectstandalone-jav)), i have these jars:
[image]

I also added the plugin path in %PATH% as follows:

```
echo %PATH% | findstr debezium
```

> XXX;C:\Users\username\Downloads\kafka\libs\debezium;

#### Help

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as i hope to replace my database polling with this debezium connector which seems a better approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution from Gunnar [here](https://groups.google.com/g/debezium/c/6k_PVrWsdYI) works! (His explanation is there too if you want to check it out.)

```
plugin.path=C:\\Users\\username\\Downloads\\kafka\\libs
```

and that also works:

```
plugin.path=C:/Users/username/Downloads/kafka/libs
plugin.path=C:\Users\username\Downloads\kafka\libs
plugin.path=/Users/username/Downloads/kafka/libs
```

The mistake is: `plugin.path` should be up to libs and not libs/debezium