# Could not initialize class io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnectorConfig

Tags: debezium

#### Set-up/Configuration

In case, it's needed, it's at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64020651/error-stopping-due-to-error-org-apache-kafka-connect-cli-connectdistributed-ja) SO question.

#### Issue

localhost:8083 is working fine as i am getting:

> {"version":"2.6.0","commit":"62abe01bee039651","kafka_cluster_id":"k6c8D2yvR5OcVFMVZayP9A"}

But when i post a connector configuration to `localhost:8083/connectors`, i am getting a `500 Server Error.` I am not posting the json body as it's not relevant.

#### Error

> WARN /connectors (org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel)
> javax.servlet.ServletException:
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException:
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/debezium/DebeziumException
> at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:408)
> at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
> at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:365)
> at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:318)
> at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:760)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:547)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1607)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1297)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:485)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1577)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1212)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:221)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:173)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:500)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:547)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:270)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException:
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/debezium/DebeziumException
> at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.rethrow(ResponseWriter.java:254)
> at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.failure(ResponseWriter.java:236)
> at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:436)
> at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:261)
> at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
> at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
> at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
> at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
> at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
> at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
> at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:232)
> at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:679)
> at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:392)
> ... 30 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/debezium/DebeziumException
> at io.debezium.relational.HistorizedRelationalDatabaseConnectorConfig.(HistorizedRelationalDatabaseConnectorConfig.java:52)
> at io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnector.config(OracleConnector.java:51)
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.validateConnectorConfig(AbstractHerder.java:366)
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.lambda$validateConnectorConfig$1(AbstractHerder.java:326)
> at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> ... 1 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.debezium.DebeziumException
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:104)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
> ... 9 more [2020-09-23 17:51:57,186] WARN unhandled due to prior sendError (org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannelState)
> javax.servlet.ServletException:
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException:
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/debezium/DebeziumException
> at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:408)
> at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
> at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:365)
> at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:318)
> at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:760)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:547)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1607)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1297)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:485)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1577)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1212)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:221)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:173)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:500)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:547)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:270)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException:
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/debezium/DebeziumException
> at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.rethrow(ResponseWriter.java:254)
> at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.failure(ResponseWriter.java:236)
> at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:436)
> at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:261)
> at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
> at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
> at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
> at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
> at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
> at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
> at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:232)
> at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:679)
> at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:392)
> ... 30 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/debezium/DebeziumException
> at io.debezium.relational.HistorizedRelationalDatabaseConnectorConfig.(HistorizedRelationalDatabaseConnectorConfig.java:52)
> at io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnector.config(OracleConnector.java:51)
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.validateConnectorConfig(AbstractHerder.java:366)
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.lambda$validateConnectorConfig$1(AbstractHerder.java:326)
> at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> ... 1 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.debezium.DebeziumException
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:104)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
> ... 9 more

#### instantclient

```
echo %PATH% | findstr instantclient
XXX;C:\Users\username\Downloads\instantclient_19_8;XXX
```

Any pointers would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue solved, i had to copy all the jars found in the **plug-in** archive [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/debezium/debezium-connector-oracle/1.2.4.Final/debezium-connector-oracle-1.2.4.Final-plugin.tar.gz).